# Should you be notified if a subscribed card is moved to another list?

Tags: trello, notifications

If I subscribe to a card (but not assigned) and there's activity on it, I'm supposed to get a notification right? When people move their cards to different lists, I don't get a notification in Trello or an email. Is that a bug or is that normal?

Answer (score 2):

According to Trello's blog on subscribe:
 "When you subscribe, you get a notification about anything that happens to that card: when somebody comments, when somebody gets added, and when it ceremoniously gets moved to the done list."

Did you have the board open when this change happened? You won't get a notification if you were already viewing the board. If you were not logged into Trello or on another board, you should receive the red notification indicator in the top right hand corner.

As far as emailing goes, also check to make sure your notification of emails is set to 'instantly' under notifications in your user profile.